# My href link to other html pages wont work

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, href

i've made a change to the navigation from scrolling in only one page to linking them to other pages instead. but i cant seem to make the href link work after that. i dont know what could be the problem here

i havent made any changes to the CSS, originally it was meant to be a **navigation for one page**, but im changing it to **navigation to other pages**

im pretty sure i need to do something to the css but im not sure what
it is

---

```
 class="sidebar-navigation hidde-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" style=" margin-top:13px;width:100%;height:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <span class="rect"></span>
                        <span class="circle"></span>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    
                    <a href="company.html">
                        <span class="rect"></span>
                        <span class="circle"></span>
                        Company
                    </a>
                </li>
```

---

```
.sidebar-navigation nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
  transform: translateX(-60%) translateY(-60%);
}

.sidebar-navigation ul {
  margin-left: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-navigation li{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.sidebar-navigation span{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.sidebar-navigation nav a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.circle{
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.rect{
  height: 1px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5.5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s, width 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s, width 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.1s, width 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant CSS and frameworks and plugins if any

Comment: "Won't work" in what way? Does it go to the wrong page? Does the new page not load? Or can you not click on the links? Or something else?

Comment: If you need page only one page, call them with `<a href="index.html#idpage">Home</a>`

Comment: nothing happens when i click on the link. supposedly, i can click on the Home and Company words and link to other pages. but nothing happens.

Comment: im linking them to other pages